# SciDB C++ (Windows) Connection using Protocol Buffers

Tags: c++, buffer, protocol-buffers, winsock2, scidb

I am trying to connect my scidb server directly via sockets using C++ under windows environment (Winsock2).
I could only find a python example below for the above purpose which seems quite outdated. 
https://github.com/artyom-smirnov/scidb4py
The .proto file shipped with the SciDB 14.12 and the one used in the python example are very much different so the example does not work with the SciDB 14.12.
If someone could help me with preferably a C++ (Windows/Linux) working example or update the existing python example.
Atleast if someone could guide me to the documentation part which explains how to use the message format outlined in the .proto file and what to expect in return.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you may be looking for is https://github.com/Paradigm4/shim.

It is a HTTP API for SciDB. All you have to do is to install this together with your SciDB. You would then use directly your Winsock (or a HTTP protocol library) directly in C/C++, connecting to the SHIM instance.